# How to resize text on a multiline label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have been playing with this code and tried all the other answers on this website but nothing seems to quite work, if a word is too long it does not wrap the word but splits the word in two. What is the proper way to resize text on a multiline label so it resizes to fit across the multiple lines?

Thanks

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 150, 100)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway" size:35.0]];
label.baselineAdjustment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
fitLabel.minimumScaleFactor=0.2;
label.text = @"Random Text";
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Can you clarify... what would you like to have happen to @"Random Text", and what's happening now that you don't desire?

Comment: You can't have `numberOfLines` set to 0. Xcode will just add more lines until the text fits without it shrinking. Either set the number of lines to 1, 2, etc. or change something else to make everything fit

Answer (score 0):

The property you’re missing is [`lineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode):

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this doesn't seem to work for multiline sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the number of lines = 0 the label will automatically break to a new line base on length of itself. I usually set the number of lines to 0 and set label height constraint <= someNumber to keep layout and control line break as well.

Comment: Tried making it 0,1,2 and 3 and nothing seemed to change sorry.

Comment: Try to set height of your label to 100, number ò line  = 0 and let see

Answer (score 0):

hey you have missed sizeToFit of uilable, just add

`[label sizeToFit]` into your code and try again.
let us know if that makes any effect, i think this could be the main bug.

Comment: Didn't seem to help sorry, thanks for the suggestion.